# End of Week - Needs to be Monday

Tags: date, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Query, where I need the week ending date to appear as Monday. I tested the following code, but received responses on Saturday, Sunday, Monday, etc. Please help?

```
SELECT DATEADD(DD, 7-(DATEPART(DW, MIN([Date])))
  , MIN([Date])) AS EndOfWeek, COUNT(*) AS TermsPerWeek

FROM Table

WHERE [Date] NOT LIKE 'null' 
 AND ([Date] LIKE '%2016%' OR [Date] LIKE '%2017%')

GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK,[Date]);
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Answer (score 0):

Using [**`set datefirst`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx):

```
set datefirst = 2
```

This will treat the start of the week as Tuesday, and the end as Monday.